# libGDX Tiled maps resizing in code

Tags: libgdx, tiles

I just started using libGDX tiled maps. And i have a question: is it possible to re size tile width and height in game so maps will be the same size on all devices (for example 1 tile equals 1/10 of screen width & 1/10th of screen height) if resizing tiles is not possible how do i make map take whole screen on any phone? is there another way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out you can scale tiled map . so what you have to do is

```
 otmr = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(tiledMap,SCREEN_WIDTH/(tiledMap.getProperties().get("width",Integer.class)*32f));
```

where 32 is  size of tile it is important that you keep your tiled map 16/9 proportions